# Укажите ошибки в предложениях и укажите их тип

Tags: грамотная-речь

1. Благодаря этому он взрослел, многому учился, делал героические поступки.
2. Поставленная автором проблема раскрывается на примере диалога Николая Степановича и Кати.
   3.Он понял, что хорошо учась, он тем самым поможет родителям, которые трудятся для него же.
3. Если взять прошлогоднюю статистику по пожарам, то наступает жуть.
4. Таким образом, родина у нас своя и , несмотря ни на что, людям нужно любить свой родной край.
5. Безразличие любви Онегиным погубило их возможный союз.
6. Дворник завел собаку, которая бегает по двору, на замечания жильцов отвечает нецензурной бранью.
7. Это доказательство тому, что любовь без дела мертва.
8. Существуют люди, которые не только увлекаются, но и посвящают искусству свою жизнь.
9. Продолжение любви проявляется во впускании партнера в свою жизнь, складывании две жизни в одну.